# npm not installing dependency of dev dependency when it's also listed as app dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, installation

This one has me stumped. Very easily reproducible.

package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-less": "^4.0.1"
    }
}
```

Put that in a folder and run `npm install --only=dev`. I'm using node v8.9.4 and npm v6.4.1.

Everything will install fine. Open the `node_modules` directory and verify that the `less` module is there, because it's a dependency of `gulp-less`. You can use this gulpfile.js to test:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
gulp.task('default')
```

Okay, now add `"less": "^3.8.1"` to "dependencies" so your package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "less": "^3.8.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-less": "^4.0.1"
    }
}
```

Remove the `node_modules` folder and package lock file and re-run `npm install --only=dev`.

You will see that you cannot run the gulp file now, and if you open and look for the `less` package in `node_modules` it will not have been installed.

This is repeatable behavior for me. Any time I add less to the app dependencies, it is never installed when I do `install --only=dev`.

Am I missing something about how this is supposed to work or did I find a bug?

Comment: I have found the issue on the old npm github! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12184 still no solution there.